# How to know whether a string can be segmented into two strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I was asked in interview following question. I could not figure out how to approach this question. Please guide me.

Question: How to know whether a string can be segmented into two strings - like breadbanana is segmentable into bread and banana, while breadbanan is not. You will be given a dictionary which contains all the valid words.

Comment: I think he's asking for both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of the words you have in the dictionary, which will make searching faster.
Search the tree according to the following letters of your input string. When you've found a word, which is in the tree, recursively start from the position after that word in the input string. If you get to the end of the input string, you've found one possible fragmentation. If you got stuck, come back and recursively try another words.

EDIT: sorry, missed the fact, that there must be just two words.
In this case, limit the recursion depth to 2.

The pseudocode for 2 words would be:

```
T = trie of words in the dictionary
for every word in T, which can be found going down the tree by choosing the next letter of the input string each time we move to the child:
    p <- length(word)
    if T contains input_string[p:length(intput_string)]:
        return true
return false
```

Assuming you can go down to a child node in the trie in `O(1)` (ascii indexes of children), you can find all prefixes of the input string in `O(n+p)`, where `p` is the number of prefixes, and `n` the length of the input. Upper bound on this is `O(n+m)`, where `m` is the number of words in dictionary. Checking for containing will take `O(w)` where `w` is the length of word, for which the upper bound would be `m`, so the time complexity of the algorithm is `O(nm)`, since `O(n)` is distributed in the first phase between all found words.

But because we can't find more than `n` words in the first phase, the complexity is also limited to `O(n^2)`.
So the search complexity would be `O(n*min(n, m))`
Before that you need to build the trie which will take `O(s)`, where `s` is the sum of lengths of words in the dictionary. The upper bound on this is `O(n*m)`, since the maximum length of every word is `n`.

Comment: Interesting. My idea was to use a trie to locate the first word, and if found do a quick, constant time search for the second word in the dictionary. I think that beats most of the other proposed solutions by a wide margin. In any case, +1 to you.

Comment: @Perception: That's still `O(n)` search, no?

Comment: @MichałTrybus: It would be helpful if your answer included the time complexity of your proposed algorithm.

Comment: Well, the trie search is O(m) where m is the input length of the string, and the hash lookup of course is constant time.

Comment: @Perception: actually the hash lookup is O(m) also. Reasonable hash functions on strings scan the characters in it.

Comment: @EyalSchneider - are you mixing up the calculation of the hashcode with the hash table lookup?

Comment: @Perception: As I understand it, a hash table lookup on K starts with calculating the hash code of K. That's how Java does it for example (it also caches the result for later use in case of a string key).

Answer (score 4):

you go through your dictionary and compare every term as a substring with the original term e.g. "breadbanana". If the first term matches with the first substring, cut the first term out of the original search term and compare the next dictionary entries with the rest of the original term...

let me try to explain that in java:
e.g.

```
    String dictTerm = "bread";
    String original = "breadbanana";

    // first part matches
    if (dictTerm.equals(original.substring(0, dictTerm.length()))) {
        // first part matches, get the rest
        String lastPart = original.substring(dictTerm.length());

        String nextDictTerm = "banana";

        if (nextDictTerm.equals(lastPart)) {
            System.out.println("String " + original +
                " contains the dictionary terms " +
                dictTerm + " and " + lastPart);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

Split the string between every pair of consecutive characters and see whether or not both substrings (to the left of the split point and to the right of it) are in the dictionary.

Comment: And what was the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

`Put all elements of dictionary in some set or list`
now you can use `contains` & `substring` function to remove words which matches dictionary. if at the end string is null ->  string can be segmented else not. You can also take care of count.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean canBeSegmented(String s) {
    for (String word : dictionary.getWords()) {
        if (s.contains(word) {
            String sub = s.subString(0, s.indexOf(word)); 
            s = sub + s.subString(s.indexOf(word)+word.length(), s.length()-1);
        }

        return s.equals("");
    }
}
```

This code checks if your given String can be fully segmented. It checks if a word from the dictionary is inside your string and then subtracks it. If you want to segment it in the process you have to order the subtracted sementents in the order they are inside the word.

Just two words makes it easier:

```
public boolean canBeSegmented(String s) {
    boolean wordDetected = false;

    for (String word : dictionary.getWords()) {
        if (s.contains(word) {
            String sub = s.subString(0, s.indexOf(word)); 
            s = sub + s.subString(s.indexOf(word)+word.length(), s.length()-1);

            if(!wordDetected) 
                wordDetected = true;
            else 
                return s.equals("");
        }

        return false;
     }
}
```

This code checks for one Word and if there is another word in the String and just these two words it returns true otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

this is a mere idea , you can implement it better if you want

```
package farzi;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringPossibility {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "breadbanana";
        ArrayList<String> dict = new ArrayList<String>();
        dict.add("bread");
        dict.add("banana");
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            String word1 = str.substring(0,i);
            String word2 = str.substring(i,str.length());
            System.out.println(word1+"===>>>"+word2);
            if(dict.contains(word1))
            {
                System.out.println("word 1 found : "+word1+" at index "+i);
            }
            if(dict.contains(word2))
            {
                System.out.println("word 2 found : "+ word2+" at index "+i);
            }
        }

    }

}
```